# How can I authenticate user against dynamic path?

Tags: symfony

is there a way in symfony2 to authenticate user for dynamic path ?

For example if i have a firewall like this:

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
```

and after login user path looks like this `/someSlug/...` is there a way to authenticate them only for that pattern? so multiple users can be loggedin ? Normally if i would know the slugs i would set up multiple firewalls

```
    main1:
        pattern: ^/slug1/
    main2:
        pattern: ^/slug2/
```

and it's done, but i need it dynamically because i don't know how much slugs there is gona be and what they are.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-box, I suspect probably not.

### Idea #1:

If this is administrative work you should be use to use Use impersanation.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html

### Idea #2:

If this is a general purpose use for this (other than administrative) you should be probably able to set **kernel request** listener that will listen for each request, parse out the given `slug` and set set `User` object in session. That object is to be used by controllers and templates.

What do you think?

Comment: it is general purpose, so according to second idea how do you want to store all logged in users? so when i login to another one the one before would not be logged out ? how to you want to store them / because there can be more users assigned to one slug, but only one slug can be assigned to one user.

Comment: That complicates things. When you say "login" do you really mean password input or something simpler?

Comment: Ok, this one is though. I am upvoting the question in hope someone else with better understanding of security fundamentals would notice it.